# GroupBy and Filter with Pandas, but using `value_counts`

Tags: pandas, dataframe

With a DataFrame having 2 columns `a` and `b`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'x'],
                   [1, 'y'],
                   [2, 'z'],
                   [1, 'x'],
                   [4, 'z'],
                   [1, 'z']],
                  columns=['a', 'b'])
```

I would like to keep only the "rows" where I have the same value on the `b` column at least twice. To do that I could use:

```py
df.groupby(by=['b']).filter(lambda b: len(b) > 1)

    a   b
0   1   x
2   2   z
3   1   x
4   4   z
5   1   z
```

Would be possible to achieve the same result using `value_counts()`?

For instance with a mask like:

```py
df['b'].value_counts() > 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `value_counts`, you can use:

```
>>> df[df['b'].isin(df['b'].value_counts().gt(1).loc[lambda x: x].index)]
   a  b
0  1  x
2  2  z
3  1  x
4  4  z
5  1  z
```

A better way with `duplicated`:

```
>>> df[df.duplicated('b', keep=False)]
   a  b
0  1  x
2  2  z
3  1  x
4  4  z
5  1  z
```

Another alternative with `value_counts`:

```
>>> df[df['b'].map(df['b'].value_counts()) > 1]
   a  b
0  1  x
2  2  z
3  1  x
4  4  z
5  1  z
```

Comment: The first one is really convoluted ;)

Comment: Using `duplicated` is more than 2 times faster than the (last) `value_counts` implementation with a dataframe with few millions rows I am using right now. Thanks! However, using `value_counts().gt(1)` in your last implementation gives a comparable performance

Comment: @mozway. I know but I didn't find simpler except with mapping :-(

Comment: @FilippoVitale. Do you mean `value_counts().gt(1)` is faster than `value_counts() > 1`? Or do you mean the first implementation?

Comment: Yes @Corralien, with the current dataframe I'm testing this out it seems that `value_counts().gt(1)` is faster than `value_counts() > 1` and almost as fast as your brilliant `df.duplicated` solution